# User agent, extract OS and browser from string

Tags: php, browser, operating-system, user-agent

I'd like to extract full the OS name and browser from the user agent string. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest looking at something like https://github.com/dmolsen/ua-parser-php to achieve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is tricky to get the full OS name and full browser name since many browsers identify themselves differently. You will probably need some fancy regex and then it might not even work 100% of the time.

Here is the simple method I use to identify the browser. You may be able to adapt it to suit your needs.

```
<?php

public static function getUserAgent()
{
    static $agent = null;

    if ( empty($agent) ) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ( stripos($agent, 'Firefox') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'firefox';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'MSIE') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'ie';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'iPad') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'ipad';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Android') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'android';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Chrome') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'chrome';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Safari') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'safari';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'AIR') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'air';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Fluid') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'fluid';
        }

    }

    return $agent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@augustknight: Note, the IE11 doesn´t send a "MSIE" token, i would suggest to add a match to a Trident token.

IE 11 user agent sample:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

change code:

```
<?php
public static function getUserAgent()
{
    static $agent = null;

    if ( empty($agent) ) {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ( stripos($agent, 'Firefox') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'firefox';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'MSIE') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'ie';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Trident') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'ie';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'iPad') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'ipad';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Android') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'android';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Chrome') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'chrome';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Safari') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'safari';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'AIR') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'air';
        } elseif ( stripos($agent, 'Fluid') !== false ) {
            $agent = 'fluid';
        }

    }

    return $agent;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

There's also a built-in function in PHP to achieve this and more: [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

```
$agent = get_browser();
echo $agent->platform;
echo $agent->parent; // or $agent->browser . $agent->version
```