# Printing the name of the browser using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User agent, extract OS and browser from string [PHP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693574/user-agent-extract-os-and-browser-from-string-php)

I simply want to print the name of the browser that a user is using to visit a `php` page, using `php` itself. For this, I am doing

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```

But this prints the following when i am using Google Chrome

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
```

Why is this happening ? And how can I get the actual name of the browser using PHP ?

Comment: This IS actual name of a browser? What do you want to get?

Comment: Here I want to get `Google Chrome`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent

Comment: @CSSS, Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693574/user-agent-extract-os-and-browser-from-string-php). You need to deduce user friendly name yourself or by using some lookup table.